# Check for score trend

Tags: r, dplyr

I have customer scoring data as follows:

```
cust_id  score_date   score
   1       5/1/2016    80
   1       5/2/2016    83
   1       5/22/2016   90
   2       6/1/2016    92
   2       7/2/2016    87
```

and I want to check the customer's scores *trend*; meaning, I'd like to check if the customer's score increased over time or not (*positive trend*).

I thought of using something like this (with `dplyr`):

```
results <- df %>% 
           group_by(cust_id) %>%
           .[order(-.[, 2]), ]
```

but I'm not so sure how to check the score's difference.

I'd like my answer set to count the number of customers with positive trend; something like:

```
      positive_trend (number of customers)
yes       1,000
no         78
```

Your help will be appreciated

Comment: @akrun Are you sure that's a duplicate? Your link is a simple group/aggregate operation while the question here is much more complex and involves intermediate computational steps.

Comment: @UweBlock You are right.  It was a bit complex.  Removed the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr`. For every `cust_id` we calculate the difference between consecutive rows with `diff` and then `summarise` them to count number of positive and negative values.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(cust_id) %>%
  mutate(difference = c(0, diff(score))) %>%
  summarise(yes = sum(difference > 0), 
            no = sum(difference < 0))


#   cust_id   yes    no
#   <int>   <int>  <int>
#1    1       2      0
#2    2       0      1
```

NOTE : According to this code, the first row in every group would be neglected as there is no trend at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,  as.list(table(factor(diff(score)>0, levels = c(TRUE, FALSE),
                                labels = c("yes", "no")))), cust_id]
#   cust_id yes no
#1:       1   2  0
#2:       2   0  1
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
table(transform(stack(with(df, tapply(score, cust_id,
                    FUN = diff)))[2:1], values = values > 0))
```